# Discord.JS | How to use the **channel.client** function without it bringing up the bot client information?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to use the **ChannelUpdate** event on Discord.js on my bot, when a channel is updated I log the old information of the channel such as name, id, type, creator, etc. And then I log the updated information of the channel. Everything else works fine but when I try and use **channel.client.user.username** to get the creator of the channel it ends up displaying the bot's username instead. How do I fix this? Code below.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', () => {

    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is now online!`)
});

// Channel Update Event ---

bot.on('channelUpdate', oldChannel => {

    console.log(`${oldChannel.name} has been updated in ${oldChannel.guild.name} the info for the channel is below:`);
    console.log(`Channel Name Before: ${oldChannel.name}`);
    console.log(`Channel ID Before: ${oldChannel.id}`);
    console.log(`Channel Creator Before: ${oldChannel.client.user.username}`);
    console.log(`Channel Type Before: ${oldChannel.type}`);
    console.log(`Channel Creation Date Before: ${oldChannel.createdAt}`);

    console.log(`Channel Name Now: ${channel.name}`);
    console.log(`Channel ID Now: ${channel.id}`);
    console.log(`Channel Creator Now: ${guild.channel.client.user}`);
    console.log(`Channel Type Now: ${channel.type}`);
    console.log(`Channel Creation Date Now: ${channel.createdAt}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, the `client` property on anything will only ever bring up your own bot client, as it is the *bot's* client communicating with Discord to retrieve things like channels and guilds. On top of that, it would be much too dangerous to have access to any other user's client (imagine what you could do by accessing their `client.token`).

For your situation here, you might be able to do something by fetching the audit logs of the guild to find out who updated the channel. [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs) is the link to the docs regarding `Guild.fetchAuditLogs()`.

Comment: I didn't think of it that way, but you're entirely correct. Thanks for the helpful link as well.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say you need oldChannel **AND** newChannel.

```
client.on("channelUpdate", async (oldChannel, newChannel) => { 

    console.log(`${oldChannel.name} has been updated in ${oldChannel.guild.name} the info for the channel is below:`);
    console.log(`Channel Name Before: ${oldChannel.name}`);
    console.log(`Channel ID Before: ${oldChannel.id}`);
    console.log(`Channel Creator Before: ${oldChannel.client.user.username}`);
    console.log(`Channel Type Before: ${oldChannel.type}`);
    console.log(`Channel Creation Date Before: ${oldChannel.createdAt}`);

    console.log(`Channel Name Now: ${newChannel.name}`);
    console.log(`Channel ID Now: ${newChannel.id}`);
    console.log(`Channel Creator Now: ${newChannel.guild.channel.client.user}`);
    console.log(`Channel Type Now: ${newChannel.type}`);
    console.log(`Channel Creation Date Now: ${newChannel.createdAt}`);

});
```

This should be the information you're looking for.